# Sorting data in gql function from @apollo/client

Tags: sorting, next.js, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

Faced a problem. The project is based on NextJS and uses the ***@apollo/client*** library. I have a query like:

```
export const GET_USERS = gql`
    query User($uid: Int){
        users(pagination: { limit: -1 }, sort: "guid, uid", filters: {uid: {eq: $uid}}){
            data{
            ....
```

where ***guid*** and ***uid*** are integer fields.
And Users are obtained in ascending order, which is obvious.
I need the sort to be in descending order, i.e. from the largest value in ***guid*** to the smallest.

How to sort in descending order for the ***guid*** field?

Tried different options and ***sort: "guid desc, uid"*** ***sort: "guid(desc), uid"*** ***sort: "guid: desc, uid"*** and so on. Tried to use ***sorts***, ***sortBy***, ***order***, ***orderBy***, swears at them that unknown arguments. I tried to put an object in ***sort***, swears, says that ***the string type was expected***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be ingeniously simple: The `sort: "guid: desc, uid"`  option was the closest. Correct: `sort: "guid:desc, uid"`, i.e. after ***:*** no space needed...

Answer (score 0):

export const GET_USERS = gql`
query User($uid: Int){
users(pagination: { limit: -1 }, sort: { guid: -1, uid: 1 }, filters: {uid: {eq: $uid}}){
data{
....

Comment: I got an error: ```Error: String cannot represent a non string value: {guid: -1, uid: 1}:```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).